# bookdownplus: dnd template error ! Undefined control sequence. l.61 \hypertarget

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, tinytex

I'm using `bookdownplus` `R` package with `dnd` template. I used the following code.

```
library('bookdownplus')
bookdownplus('dnd', render = TRUE, rproj = TRUE)
```

When I compile the document, it throws the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.61 \hypertarget
                 {chapter-1-bookdownplus}
```

Any hints to solve the issue. Thanks

**Session Info**

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] bookdownplus_1.5.6

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.1      bookdown_0.9.2  packrat_0.5.0   digest_0.6.18  
 [5] magrittr_1.5    evaluate_0.13   stringi_1.4.3   rstudioapi_0.10
 [9] rmarkdown_1.12  tools_3.5.3     stringr_1.4.0   tinytex_0.11   
[13] xfun_0.6        yaml_2.2.0      compiler_3.5.3  htmltools_0.3.6
[17] knitr_1.22.8
```

**Edited**

Using the suggestions of @Maurits Evers, I updated [TinyTex](https://yihui.name/tinytex/) using `wget -qO- "https://yihui.name/gh/tinytex/tools/install-unx.sh" | sh` on `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS`. I stilling getting the error: `! Undefined control sequence.
l.61 \hypertarget
                 {chapter-1-bookdownplus}{%

Error: Failed to compile dnd.tex. See https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips.` Any thoughts.

**Bug Reported**

Bug is reported [tinytex](https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/issues/111) and [bookdownplus](https://github.com/pzhaonet/bookdownplus/issues/45).

Comment: Your error message says to run `get_templates`. Did you? I did, and it shows that there's a template called "dnd", not one called "dnd_dev". This seems to be an easily fixed typo.

Comment: Thanks @camille for your comment. The commands were taken from [bookdownplus website](https://bookdownplus.netlify.com/portfolio/dnd/). However, after changing `dnd_dev` to `dnd` works. However, it does not compile properly and throws the error: `! Undefined control sequence.
l.61 \hypertarget
                 {chapter-1-bookdownplus}`. Any thoughts and hints, please.

Comment: I don't know, but if the question is no longer about your typo, you should probably at least edit the question and title to reflect what it's actually about

Comment: @camille: Edited the question and title to reflect the problem.

Comment: I can reproduce on Ubuntu 18.10, running TexLive, with bookdownplus ver. 1.5.6. The dnd.tex file is missing the preamble command \usepackage{hyperref}. If I add this manually into the tex file, it compiles fine.  Looks like a bookdownplus bug, where they forgot to include this statement in the template on this version

Comment: Hmm, odd, I double-checked and I have no issues with `bookdownplus_1.5.6` on MacOS running MacTex. I still wonder if this is an issue with the minimal `tinytex` LaTeX environment. An option would be to install a full TeX distribution and then try again; or perhaps try installing `hyperref` through `tinytex` with `tlmgr install hyperref` and then try re-compiling the document.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your issue on MacOS running MacTex with `bookdownplus_1.5.6`.

```
library('bookdownplus')
bookdownplus('dnd', render = TRUE, rproj = TRUE)
```

gives the following output

```
#trying URL 'https://github.com/pzhaonet/bookdownplus/raw/master/upload/dnd/demo.zip'
#Content type 'application/zip' length 3325858 bytes (3.2 MB)
#==================================================
#downloaded 3.2 MB
#
#
#
#processing file: dnd.Rmd
#  |......................                                           |  33%
#  ordinary text without R code
#
#  |...........................................                      |  67%
#label: unnamed-chunk-1 (with options)
#List of 2
# $ type  : chr "quotebox"
# $ engine: chr "block"
#
#  |.................................................................| 100%
#  ordinary text without R code
#
#
#output file: dnd.knit.md
#
#/usr/local/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS dnd.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output dnd.tex --table-of-contents --toc-depth 3 --template tex/template_dnd_dev.tex --number-sections --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --natbib --top-level-division=chapter --variable tables=yes --standalone
#
#Output created: _book/dnd.pdf
```

[image]

I think the issue might be related to your incomplete/missing LaTeX environment. The error you're seeing suggests that you are missing the [`hyperref` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref?lang=en). Depending on your OS, I believe that most (all?) standard (La)TeX distributions (e.g. MacTex/TeX Live on MacOS, MiKTeX on Windows, ...) include `hyperref` by default. So the first thing to do is to ensure that you have a working TeX distribution on your OS. Then try re-compiling the `bookdownplus` example.

---

### Making sure that you have a functional TeX distribution

Let's create a sample LaTeX file `test.tex` with the following content

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\href{https://www.r-project.org}{The R Project for Statistical Computing}
\end{document}
```

Store the file in a folder and from that same folder open an R terminal and compile the document with

```
tinytex::pdflatex("test.tex")
```

The output should be a PDF file `test.pdf`.

Comment: Thanks @Maurits Evers for you reply. I updated [TinyTex](https://yihui.name/tinytex/) using `wget -qO- "https://yihui.name/gh/tinytex/tools/install-unx.sh" | sh` on `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS`. I stilling getting the error: `! Undefined control sequence.
l.61 \hypertarget
                 {chapter-1-bookdownplus}{% 

Error: Failed to compile dnd.tex. See https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips.` Any thoughts.

Comment: @MYaseen208 Did you install `tinytex` following the instructions from the link? `install.packages('tinytex'); tinytex::install_tinytex()` This still looks like you don't have the necessary TeX distribution.

Comment: @MYaseen208 I've edited my post to show how to confirm that you've got a valid TeX distribution installed by compiling a sample LaTeX document. Please take a look.

Comment: Thanks @Maurits Evers for your help. Yes, `tinytex::pdflatex("test.tex")` works fine.